# 2 files, identical contents, but grep creates a file with CRLF line terminators

Tags: bash

I have 2 identical files in terms of content.  My program reads file1 without an issue and executes the program fine.  However my program fails to do anything when reading file2, even though its the EXACT same content.  I then debugged it further and the only difference is how I created the file.

File 2 was created via a grep command and redirecting the output to a file.  File 1 was created by me manually highlighting all the contents in file 2 and putting it into file 1 via a paste.  So I wondered if it created a different file type.  I checked, and I see the following:

```
$ file file1
file1: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ file file2
file2: ASCII text
```

The exact command I used with grep was:

```
grep "interface\|switchport access vlan" somefile > file1
```

It turns out that the original file I grepped is of file type:

```
$ file somefile 
somefile: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

So grep is inheriting this file type in the new file.  I don't understand what this formatting problem is, but it's definitely related to this file type.  Can anyone explain why this file type breaks my program.

If you need to see the program, I put this below:

```
$ cat y
#!/bin/bash

vlan=119
prev=

##grep " interface\|vlan" > file2
while read line
do
    if ([ ! -z "${prev}" ] && [ "$line" = "switchport access vlan $vlan" ]);then
        line1="${prev}"
        line2="${line}"
        echo "${line1}"
        echo "${line2}"
    fi
    prev="${line}"
done < file1
```

the result with file1 is a loads of lines stating similar to:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/26
switchport access vlan 119
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/29
switchport access vlan 119
```

The result with file2 is absolutely nothing.

Comment: The files do not have the same content since one has Windows line endings and the other does not.

Comment: So why does it break the program?

Comment: Because your script expects Windows line endings I would presume. Are you running a Windows version  of bash / grep / etc ? You can convert the line endings in text files with `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The two files have different line endings; run `head -1 <filename> | od -c` and you should see:

- `file1` line ends in ***2*** characters - `\r \n`
- `file2` line ends in ***1*** character - `\n`

When you read `file1` into the `line` variable you're also pulling that `\r` into the variable (run `od -c <<< "$line"` to confirm).  This additional `\r` on the end of `$line` means the follow-on *exact* match won't actually match.

While you could add the `\r` to the comparison, it's probably best to strip the `\r` from the input.

A few ideas:

- `dos2unix file1` - remove `\r` characters; actually updates the file sans the `\r` characters
- `grep ... somefile | tr -d '\r' > file1` - strip the `\r` before it's written to `file1`
- `while read line; .... done < <(tr -d '\r' < file1)` - strip the `\r` while reading from `file1`
- inside the loop add `line="${line//$'\r'/}"` - strip the trailing `\r` from the variable